# Get text between two tags and make another NSString from it

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, nsstring, asihttprequest

I have html page with html code (NSString) like this:

```
<html>
<p>
textA
</p>
<p>
textB
</p>
</html>
<a>
textC
</a>
```

And I want to get text between tags

and make another NSString.
Expected result with this code is:

> textAtextB

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had to replace

```
[a]text[/a]
```

with

```
<a href="text">text</a>
```

This is how I fixed it:

```
NSString *xml = @"[a]text[/a][a]awesome[/a]"
NSString *pattern = @"\\[a\\](.*?)\\[\\/a\\]";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                  error:nil];
for( NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult in [regex matchesInString:xml options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, xml.length)] )
{
    NSRange matchRange = [textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *match = [xml substringWithRange:matchRange];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[a]%@[/a]",match] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>",match,match] ];
    NSLog(@"Found string '%@'", match);
}
```

This will output:

```
<a href="text">text</a>
<a href="awesome">awesome</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for a < sign, then for the next > sign, and delete the part. Repeat until you don't have those signs left.
Replace the regex <*> with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) Framework to your project.

Add the flag `-licucore` to your `Other Linker Flags` of your project settings
Add `#import "RegexKitLite.h"` in your class

Then use this snippet to eliminate all tags:

```
NSString *tags = @"<[^>]*>"; 
NSString *htmlString=@"<html><p>textA</p><p>textB</p></html>";;
NSString *stringWithoutTags = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:tags withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",stringWithoutTags);
//output: textAtextB
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to remove all tags. I want to get text between tags, because I have another tags with another text, which I don't need to show.

Comment: You could use NSScanner to scan the text, then use my snippet until you find the tag </html>.